# ccavenue payment gateway request-handler not redirecting to ccavenue-payment-gateway

Tags: php, codeigniter, ccavenue

**ccavenue payment gateway request-handler not redirecting to ccavenue-payment-gateway**..

I have setup ccAvenue request-handler form with required hidden-parameters, but its not redirecting to ccAvenue payment gateway. I tried with multiple debugs, but not working. Please suggest me changes.

My Code Snippet:

ccAvRequestHandler-

```
<?php 
       error_reporting(0);
       include('Crypto.php');

       $payment_mode = "TEST"; // TEST/LIVE 

       if($payment_mode=="TEST"){
            $action = "https://test.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction";
       }else{
            $action = "https://secure.ccavenue.com/transaction/transaction.do?command=initiateTransaction";
       }
?>

<form method="post" name="redirect" action="<?=$action?>"> 
    <?php
        echo "<input type=hidden name=encRequest value=$encrypted_data>";
        echo "<input type=hidden name=access_code value=$access_code>";
    ?>
</form>
<?php exit; ?>
<script language='javascript'>document.redirect.submit();</script>

<!--Boostrap Core js start-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**hidden input values coming properly**, but why not redirecting to ccAvenue payment gateway. **Its redirecting to blank-page means form itself.**

please suggest me the changes.

also attaching the screenshot of view-page-source code of that form.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What _are_ $encrypted_data and $access_code? You have not shown us where you are creating those, so they might simply be wrong perhaps. Or maybe the contain characters that invalidate your HTML.

Comment: @04FS please check screenshot, before processing $_POST, i printed it

Answer (score 0):

why u put

```
<?php exit; ?>
```

after form closing tag,
script is terminating there